# Is there a benefit in creating and writing to a text file in my program's code, to creating the text file and writing the data separately?

Tags: java

I started learning my first programming language this year, Java. I'm reading my textbook and I have learned how to create a text file and write to it within my source code. Then when I run the program I can see it has created the text file I called it and has written whatever I wrote in Java inside the text file. This text file is then stored in my project folder.

Is there a benefit to creating the text file and writing to it in my code? Why not just create a new text file separately where it seems a lot more convenient to write data to it? Both get the same end result if I'm not mistaken. Does it provide easier access?

EDIT:
Using a program such as Notepad to write the information in

Comment: Are you asking what is the benefit to the program writing the data, compared to you writing the data with like notepad?

Comment: @John I believe he is talking about the file creation only..?

Comment: @nestedloop Is he asking is it more convenient to write the file in the current directory, rather than write it somewhere else?

Comment: What is the benefit of programming anything if you can do it yourself manually? The point is _automation_.

Comment: To demonstrate Boris's point above, what if you had to create and write into 1000 text files, would you still rather do it manually - or would you feel that a program that's doing it for you is beneficial?

Comment: @John Exactly what I'm asking. Why not just write it with notepad?

Comment: @alfasin Maybe because I'm a beginner I see writing the data in something like Notepad as a faster way to do such a thing if I had to write 1000 text files but I see what is meant by automation.

Comment: Sometimes you don't know the data you need to write into your file since it comes from different resources, you may not even be capable of see it unless you write it somewhere, and that's when writing it into a (text) file comes handy. Also, this *data* may not mean a single line on the file but several hundreds, specially for reports.

Comment: @PhilDrach you're saying that using Notepad manually is faster than typing `for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) { Files.write(...) }`?? You must have some magic version of Notepad...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ahh I forgot about being able to use a loop for it. I see now. No magic there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are major advantages to this:

- You know what *type* of data you're going to write to disk, but you don't know the *contents* of that data.  This is prevalent in logging systems, in which we know the general kind of data we want to write to a log file, but we don't know what sort of data we'll be writing.
- You may not have direct access to write to the machine that your application is running on, and if you needed to create the file beforehand, that would introduce a whole heap of unreliability in the application.
- You may want to write to a temporary file for testing purposes, and you don't want to write out to a file for *every* test run you do.  (If you do a lot of testing, and you do tests with temp files, then you'll run into a ***lot*** of pain if you have to recreate the test file by hand.)

Anything that you can instruct the machine to do for you is a huge win in time, as well as it improves the overall stability of the system.  If there is no human interaction required to write a file to disk, then that system can sit in isolation without anyone needing to create files for the application to write to.

Comment: _If there is no human interaction required_ - this is the key point I think; no human interaction means no possibility of human error. (Beyond bugs in the code of course).

Comment: So the human interaction would, as you have in your second bullet, mean unreliability?

Comment: Yes.  My previous role as a Java developer dealt with a fairly complicated ordering system, and if there were critical failures to our redundancy systems, we needed a way to ensure that we didn't lose any transactions.  If we were required to write those specific log files out *by hand*, not only would we be losing lots and lots of valuable time, but the system would not be reliable enough to handle this scenario at a time in which the development team and support teams are asleep.  That makes the application *very* unreliable.